# Displaying python 2d list without commas, brackets, etc. and newline after every row

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to display a python 2D list without the commas, brackets, etc., and I'd like to display a new line after every 'row' of the list is over.

This is my attempt at doing so:

```
ogm = repr(ogm).replace(',', ' ')
ogm = repr(ogm).replace('[', ' ')
ogm = repr(ogm).replace("'", ' ')
ogm = repr(ogm).replace('"', ' ')
print repr(ogm).replace(']', ' ')
```

This is the input:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

This is the output:

```
"'    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    1  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0    1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1    0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0    0  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  1  1    0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  1    0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0    1  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0    '"
```

I'm encountering two problems:

1. There are stray " and ' which I can't get rid of
2. I have no idea how to do a newline

Comment: Note: using `repr` for things like this is bad practice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple way:

```
for row in list2D:
    print " ".join(map(str,row))
```

Comment: this can be `print('\n'.join(map(lambda b: ''.join(map(str, b)), list2D)))`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe join is appropriate for you:

```
print "\n".join(" ".join(str(el) for el in row) for row in ogm)

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 3):

```
print "\n".join(" ".join(map(str, line)) for line in ogm)
```

If you want the rows and columns transposed

```
print "\n".join(" ".join(map(str, line)) for line in zip(*ogm))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for row in list2D:
    print(*row)
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the display even more readable you can use tabs or fill the cells with spaces to align the columns.

```
def printMatrix(matrix):
    for lst in matrix:
        for element in lst:
            print(element, end="\t")
        print("")
```

It will display

```
6       8       99
999     7       99
3       7       99
```

instead of

```
6 8 99
999 7 99
3 7 99
```

Comment: This works, but can be (significantly) further optimized.

Answer (score -1):

```
ogm = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

s1 = str(ogm)

s2 = s1.replace('], [','\n')

s3 = s2.replace('[','')

s4 = s3.replace(']','')

s5= s4.replace(',','')

print s5
```

btw the " is actually two ' without any gap

i am learning python for a week. u guys have given some xcellent solutions. here is how i did it....this works too....... :)